# Can masked octets in network adress still be used?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I've come around following example in TCP/IP illustrated:

```
Figure 2-3. A site is allocated the classical class B network number 128.32. The
network administrator decides to apply a site-wide subnet mask of 255.255.255.0,
giving 256 subnetworks where each subnetwork can hold 256 – 2 = 254 hosts. The
IPv4 address of each host on the same subnet has the subnetwork number in
common. All of the IPv4 addresses of hosts on the left-hand LAN segment start
with 128.32.1, and all of those on the right start with 128.32.2.
```

[image]

I would imagine B class address (128.32.) with a 255.255.255.0 mask resulting in 128.32.0.[0-254] address range. The book says its 128.32.[0-254].[0-254], as fas as I understood. Can someone explain why despite third octet is masked, the book refers to 128.32.1 and 128.32.2 avaialble?

Comment: Please improve question's title.

Comment: Done, didn't realise it's not descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is saying that the network admin is subnetting the class B network `128.32.0.0/16` into 256 subnets with a netmask of `255.255.255.0` (/24 in CIDR notation): `128.32.0.0/24`, `128.32.1.0/24`, `128.32.2.0/24`... The whole `128.32` class B still routes to that site. The smaller subnets are "internal" (the rest of the internet need not be aware).

An example scenario: `128.32.0.0` is assigned to some company. Call it the Acme corporation. Acme has several departments: IT, Accounting, Sales, etc that they would like to keep on separate networks. So they assign each its own subnetwork: IT=`128.32.0.0/24`, Accounting=`128.32.1.0/24` etc. The rest of the internet does not care about these internal designations. All that matters is that the internet can reach Acme.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of a router is to send packets to a destination based on the longest prefix match. This simply refers to the specificity of a route determined by it's mask length. It's exactly analogous to putting a letter you've written to your friend in Albuquerque, NM in the mailbox. If you just write "Albuquerque, NM 87111" as the destination address on the envelope (as opposed to "12338 Anyplace Street Albuquerque, NM 87111"), your letter will get to Albuquerque - if your local postal carrier decides to not yell at you, but using an accurate address will get your letter to the right place.

Abstracting this concept to IP addresses and routes: if all three of these routes exist in a router's routing table, which one of these do you think a router would choose as the proper route to send packets to a destination, if the destination IP address is `192.168.1.75`?

```
192.168.0.0/16
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.1.64/27
```

If you guessed the third option, you'd be correct, as this is the *most specific* route to the destination address, and thus will be the route that the router uses to send the traffic to that IP address.

Now, with that said if you get your own IP space from an RIR and you want to connect to the Internet, you will be required by most transit providers (ISPs) to announce this IP space with a prefix length no longer than a /24. The point of doing this is to keep the global routing table of the Internet as small as possible.

In the example you provided, if "the site" has an entire /16 of their own IP address space, that creates a possible 256 subnets (routes) of a /24 mask length. Only under certain circumstances would the site want to do anything *besides* announce a single /16 prefix to the Internet Service Provider in order to route traffic to their network.

This concept is referred to as *route aggregation* and is generally regarded as a desirable thing to do whenever possible, especially when connecting to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

First off, recognize that TCP/IP Illustrated...while a great book (I have a copy as well), is quite dated at this point.  In modern networking, talking about IPv4 address classes as anything other than an historical footnote is going to get you into trouble really quickly.

So, think of the example this way:

A site is allocated 128.32.0.0/16, and the site administrator assigns network numbers* within the site based on a 24-bit mask, or 255.255.255.0 in dotted-quad notation.  Note that the internal networks need not all use the same network mask length, but we'll stick with them for this example.

A 24-bit netmask includes the first 3 octets in dotted-quad notation in the network portion of the IP address, so any set of IP addresses that have the first *3* octets in common are part of the same network.

This means that 128.32.0.x is a network, 128.32.1.x is a network, 128.32.2.x is a network, and so on, because all IP addresses in each network with different values of "x" still have the first 3 octets in common which is what the 24-bit netmask signifies.

Note that, in the example, 128.32.0.0/16 is never actually assigned as a /16 network to any network segment, only various networks with 24-bit network masks are.

- You'll note that I avoid the term subnet. I believe that term should be retired from usage in modern networking discussion.  I don't think its really an accurate description of what is happening anymore, as its original definition was a subnetwork of a classful IP network address.  In modern days we have networks, full stop.  Those networks can have any network mask that is appropriate and a smaller network(s) allocated from a larger allocation is not necessarily hierarchically connected to the larger allocation from a network topological point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mate! Could you recommend something more recent to read on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

In binary form:

```
128.23.0.0    = 10000000000101110000000000000000
255.255.255.0 = 11111111111111111111111100000000
```

The mask computation result would be

```
        10000000000101110000000000000000
```

The same as the net was before subnetting. So, despite third octet looks "masked" when written in decimal form, it's not. That's why we can use 128.23.*.* adresses.